# Error : Failed to delete the item from the trash

Tags: linux, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, trash

I were looking for some folders in my OS, while I clicked on /media/username/ directory and I see that weird in that directory have 100+ folders and every folder name is similar except last numbers its like

> root@usrname:~# cd /media/usrname
>
> root@usrname:/media/usrname# ls
>
> CDROM
> CDROM2    CDROM29  CDROM41  CDROM54  CDROM67  CDROM8   CDROM92 CDROM1
> CDROM20   CDROM3   CDROM42  CDROM55  CDROM68  CDROM80  CDROM93 CDROM10
> CDROM21   CDROM30  CDROM43  CDROM56  CDROM69  CDROM81  CDROM94
> CDROM100  CDROM22   CDROM31  CDROM44  CDROM57  CDROM7   CDROM82
> CDROM95 CDROM101  CDROM23   CDROM32  CDROM45  CDROM58  CDROM70
> CDROM83  CDROM96 CDROM11   CDROM24   CDROM33  CDROM46  CDROM59
> CDROM71  CDROM84  CDROM97 CDROM12   CDROM25   CDROM34  CDROM47  CDROM6
> CDROM72  CDROM85  CDROM98 CDROM13   CDROM26   CDROM35  CDROM48
> CDROM60  CDROM73  CDROM86  CDROM99 CDROM14   CDROM27   CDROM36
> CDROM49  CDROM61  CDROM74  CDROM87 CDROM15   CDROM277  CDROM37  CDROM5
> CDROM62  CDROM75  CDROM88 CDROM16   CDROM278  CDROM38  CDROM50
> CDROM63  CDROM76  CDROM89 CDROM17   CDROM279  CDROM39  CDROM51
> CDROM64  CDROM77  CDROM9 CDROM18   CDROM28   CDROM4   CDROM52  CDROM65
> CDROM78  CDROM90 CDROM19   CDROM280  CDROM40  CDROM53  CDROM66
> CDROM79  CDROM91

I deleted this folder by using
**sudo rm -rf**
but after delete I checked those folders **existed in my Trash Directory**
I unable to delete those from Trash got this permission error

**You dont have sufficient permission to delete the folder "CDROM"**

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/600392/763772

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/619966/763772 This may be a better link

Comment: **sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/** thanks its worked @Paddy